# Youtube restricted countries due to missing Referer on Cordova / Phongap

Tags: cordova, youtube, phonegap, http-referer

I'm using the simple iframe Youtube api to show videos on my Cordova app.

Problem is, a cordova app doesn't send referer, so Youtube refused to play some videos, like Vevo's ... Simple videos works fine

Is there a way to send any referer so my app can play all Youtube videos ?

Thanks in advance
Gilles